# Prove that the system $A^T A x = A^T b$ always has a solution

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, least-squares

> Prove that the system $$A^T A x = A^T b$$ always has a solution. The matrices and vectors are all real. The matrix $A$ is $m \times n$.

I think it makes sense intuitively but I can't prove it formally.

Comment: This is the classical fact that least-squares problems always have solutions (though not always unique).

Comment: @darijgrinberg I don't mean to be rude but "this is the classic fact" is not a proof :) I'm looking for a proof of the statement, I know it is true.

Comment: this is why I posted a comment, not an answer :) I'm just giving context for future readers.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Ah, excuse me! thought you were being snarky!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The matrix $A^TA$ need not be invertible. So what you need to prove is that $A^T b$ lies in the image $V= {\rm im\;} A^T A$.

Now, $A^T b\in V$ is equivalent to $V^\perp \subset (A^T b)^\perp$ so it suffices  to show that the orthogonal complement of ${\rm im} A^T A$ is also orthogonal to $A^T b$.

So suppose that $z^T A^T A=0$ (i.e. the vector $z$ is orthogonal to the image). Then also $|z^T A^T|^2 = z^T A^T A z=0$ so $z^T A^T=0$. But then $z^T A^Tb=0$ as we had to show.

Comment: What is $z$? Why is it sufficient to look at the orthogonal complement?

Comment: @Neutronic: If $A$ and $B$ are two subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $A \subseteq B$ is equivalent to $B^\perp \subseteq A^\perp$. Do you know this fact? (The $\Longrightarrow$ direction is easy. The other direction follows using $\left(C^\perp\right)^\perp = C$.)

Answer (score 5):

Let the SVD of $\mathrm A \in \mathrm R^{m \times n}$ be

$$\mathrm A = \mathrm U \Sigma \mathrm V^{\top} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm U_1 & \mathrm U_2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \hat\Sigma & \mathrm O\\ \mathrm O & \mathrm O\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm V_1^{\top}\\ \mathrm V_2^{\top}\end{bmatrix}$$

where the zero matrices may be empty. The eigendecomposition of $\mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm A$ is, thus,

$$\mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm A = \mathrm V \Sigma^{\top} \mathrm U^{\top} \mathrm U \Sigma \mathrm V^{\top} = \mathrm V \Sigma^{\top} \Sigma \mathrm V^{\top} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm V_1 & \mathrm V_2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \hat\Sigma^2 & \mathrm O\\ \mathrm O & \mathrm O\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm V_1^{\top}\\ \mathrm V_2^{\top}\end{bmatrix}$$

Hence, the **normal equations** $\mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm A \, \mathrm x = \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm b$ can be written as follows

$$\mathrm V \begin{bmatrix} \hat\Sigma^2 & \mathrm O\\ \mathrm O & \mathrm O\end{bmatrix} \mathrm V^{\top} \mathrm x = \mathrm V \begin{bmatrix} \hat\Sigma & \mathrm O\\ \mathrm O & \mathrm O\end{bmatrix} \mathrm U^{\top} \mathrm b$$

Let $\mathrm y := \mathrm V^{\top} \mathrm x$. Left-multiplying by $\mathrm V^{\top}$,

$$\begin{bmatrix} \hat\Sigma^2 & \mathrm O\\ \mathrm O & \mathrm O\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm y_1\\ \mathrm y_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \hat\Sigma & \mathrm O\\ \mathrm O & \mathrm O\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm U_1^{\top} \mathrm b\\ \mathrm U_2^{\top} \mathrm b\end{bmatrix}$$

and, thus,

$$\begin{bmatrix} \mathrm I_r & \mathrm O\\ \mathrm O & \mathrm O\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm y_1\\ \mathrm y_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \hat\Sigma^{-1} & \mathrm O\\ \mathrm O & \mathrm O\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm U_1^{\top} \mathrm b\\ \mathrm U_2^{\top} \mathrm b\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \hat\Sigma^{-1}\mathrm U_1^{\top} \mathrm b\\ \mathrm O\end{bmatrix}$$

which *always* has a solution, as $\mathrm O \mathrm y_2 = \mathrm O$ always has a solution. The affine solution space is parametrized by

$$\mathrm x = \mathrm V_1 \hat\Sigma^{-1} \mathrm U_1^{\top} \mathrm b + \mathrm V_2 \eta$$

where $\{ \mathrm V_2 \eta \mid \eta \in \mathbb R^{n-r} \}$ is the null space of $\mathrm A$. If $\mathrm A$ has **full column rank**, then $r = n$, the null space of $\mathrm A$ is $\{0_n\}$, and $\mathrm V_1 \hat\Sigma^{-1} \mathrm U_1^{\top} \mathrm b$ is the only solution to the normal equations.

---

**Addendum**

Using the SVD of $\mathrm A$, the original system $\mathrm A \mathrm x = \mathrm b$ can be written as

$$\begin{bmatrix} \hat\Sigma & \mathrm O\\ \mathrm O & \mathrm O\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm y_1\\ \mathrm y_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm U_1^{\top} \mathrm b\\ \mathrm U_2^{\top} \mathrm b\end{bmatrix}$$

which only has a solution if $\mathrm U_2^{\top} \mathrm b = \mathrm 0$, i.e., if $\mathrm b$ is orthogonal to the left null space of $\mathrm A$, i.e., if $\mathrm b$ is in the **column space** of $\mathrm A$.

Answer (score 2):

Prop 1: $ker(A^TA)=ker(A)$.

proof: suppose $x\in ker(A^TA)$, then $A^TAx=0\implies x^TA^TAx=0\implies (Ax)^TAx=0\implies Ax=0\implies x\in ker(A)$

Also, If $x\in ker(A)$, then $Ax=0\implies A^TAx=0\implies x\in ker(A^TA) \square$.

Prop 2: $A^TA=(A^TA)^T$

Prop 3: $col(A^T)+ker(A)=\mathbb{R}^m$. Since they are orthogonal complements.

Lastly, to show $A^TAx=A^Tb$ has at least one solution for all $b$,
it is equivalent to showing that $col(A^T)=col(A^TA)$.

$$\text{Prop 3: }col(A^T)+ker(A)=\mathbb{R}^m$$
$$\text{Prop 1: } col(A^T)+ker(A^TA)=\mathbb{R}^m$$
$$\text{Prop 3: applied to $A^TA$: }col((A^TA)^T)+ker(A^TA)=\mathbb{R}^m$$
$$\text{Prop 2: }col(A^TA)+ker(A^TA)=\mathbb{R}^m$$

Hence $col(A^TA)=col(A^T)\square$.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bumping but I had a solution which I liked to share.

Using the [fundamental theorem of linear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_linear_algebra) We can decompose our matrix $b$ into two matrices $b_1$ and $b_2$ such that $b_1$ is in the column space of $A$ and $b_2$ is in the null-space of $A^T$.

Now let $x^*$ be a solution to $Ax^* = b_1$ (It always has a solution since $b_1$ is in the column space of $A$. We claim that $x$ is also a solution to $A^TAx = A^Tb$.

$$A^T(Ax* - b) = A^T(b_1 - (b_1 + b_2)) = A^T(-b_2) = - A^T(b_2) = 0$$

The last equality being a consequence of $b_2$ being in the null-space of $A^T$.